# How to make this (LEFT?) JOIN work

Tags: postgresql

I've got three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE credential_types (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    ...
);

CREATE TABLE credentials (
    user_id integer REFERENCES users(id),
    credential integer REFERENCES credential_types(id),
    UNIQUE (user_id, credential)
);

CREATE TABLE users (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(64),
    username varchar(64),
    ...
);
```

Now, I want to fetch all users that exist, and I want to fetch the particular credential type they have. I tried this:

```
ribit=> SELECT u.id, u.name, u.username, ct.name AS cred \
         FROM users u, credential_types ct, credentials c \
         WHERE c.user_id=u.id AND ct.id=c.credential;
 id | name | username |  cred
----+------+----------+---------
  1 | foo  | bos      | Try-Out
(1 row)
```

Which is correct kind of output, but all the users that do not yet have a credential (null) are left out. I do not know which kind of JOIN I need for this operation. I *think* I need a LEFT JOIN, but I fail hard when I try to achieve what I want:

```
ribit=> SELECT u.id, u.name, u.username, ct.name \
        FROM users u, credential_types ct \
        LEFT JOIN credentials c ON ct.id=c.credential;
```

gives me a cross join with erronious data.

What I'm looking for are hints of how to write the query to produce the output I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The left join is not quite in the right place.

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, u.username, ct.name
FROM   users u
LEFT JOIN credentials c ON u.id = c.user_id
INNER JOIN credential_types ct ON c.credential = ct.id
```

I think this is closer to what you want.

Comment: That one almost worked. As is, it works like my "working" query, but if I change INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN (i.e. two LEFT JOINs) it's producing the output I'm striving for. However, I have no idea why or what's happening, so I guess I'll have to dive into the PG-manual once again.

Thanks.

Comment: If two left joins work, great.  The only theoretical difference would be that rows in `credentials` would not match if there was no match for them in `credential_types`, which does not look possible given the foreign key constraints.  Left join for both should be just fine in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, u.username, ct.name 
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN credentials c ON (u.id=c.user_id) 
JOIN credential_type ct ON ct.id=c.credential;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try first joining the credential tables, and then left join your users table to those results.

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, u.username, cred
FROM users u LEFT JOIN 
( SELECT ct.name AS cred, c.user_id 
  FROM credentials c JOIN credential_types ct ON c.credential=ct.id 
) ON u.id=c.user_id
```